# Automating SSAS deployment using AMO

Tags: sql-server-2012, continuous-integration, ssas, continuous-deployment, ssas-tabular

I am trying to automate the build and deployment of a number of tabular cubes on SQL Server 2012.

At this point I can generate deployment artifacts (.asdatabase, .deploymentoptions and .deploymenttargets files), I can generate an XMLA using the Deployment Wizard from command prompt and I can deploy it using an AMO Power Shell script. However, Microsoft's recommendation is to use AMO for everything.

If I was to eliminate the Deployment Wizard from the equation, is there an AMO class that ingests the .asdatabase file and creates generates the database with all the objects as defined within the "Database" tag? or do I need to parse the XML, extract each element,find the equivalent Class/Method that will produce that object in the database? That seems orders of magnitude more complex than using the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I think sticking with the deployment wizard makes sense. It can be automated with [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/deployment/deploy-model-solutions-with-the-deployment-utility?view=asallproducts-allversions&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762) parameters. I also suspect you can edit the Model.deploymentoptions file in the same folder as the .asdatabase file but I can't recall if you do that in the deployment wizard or manually.

Your other option is automating using [custom msbuild task](https://web.archive.org/web/20120728015053/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cathyk/archive/2011/08/10/deploying-tabular-projects-using-a-custom-msbuild-task.aspx). Here is a [walkthrough](http://www.blue-granite.com/blog/applying-configurations-tabular-model-ms-build) with screenshots. Note that once you upgrade to SSAS 2016 and 1200 compatibility models this option will break because the model is stored as JSON not XML.